# Yii has_many relationship with two primary_keys

Tags: php, yii, has-many, composite-primary-key

I have a `mail_conversation` and a `mail_conversation_member` table.

`mail_conversation` has only `id` as the `PRIMARY KEY`.

`mail_conversation_member` has `conversation_id` and `user_id` as `PRIMARY KEY`s.

Now, I want to list a conversation and all its members, but it only returns **one** member. It seems I need to add a second `PRIMARY KEY` in the `HAS_MANY` relationship.

```
 'message_member' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'MailConversationMember', 'conversation_id')
```

I get the conversations with:

```
 $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
        $criteria->condition = "message_member.user_id = " . Yii::app()->user->id;
        $criteria->order = 'messages.date_created DESC';

        $mail_conversations = MailConversation::model()->with(array('message_member',   'messages'))->findAll($criteria);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the criteria you have. If you take the 'message_member' out of the `with` array, you can lazy load the members once you have the conversations. You should check the SQL code that Yii is generating to confirm that the criteria is being interpreted as expected.

In addition, why not define a relationship in the member class:

```
'conversations' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'MailConversationMember', 'user_id',array(
     'order' => 'messages.date_created DESC',
),
```

Then you can pull the conversations through without that criteria you have specified, and pull the members through on each conversation.